# Configuring jhipster-registry v3.0.3 with Git repo

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

I am trying to use the pre-packaged v3.0.3 war file for the jhipster-registry. I am launching it with these command-line properties in an attempt to point it to my Git repo for configuration info:

```
jhipster-registry-3.0.3.war --spring.profiles.active=prod,cust1 \
--spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=http://myserver/url/MyConfig \
--spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=user \
--spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=pass
```

It starts, but I always get this error:

```
Your JWT secret key is not set up, you will not be able to log into the JHipster
```

I've tried many combinations of how to setup the Git repo. I'm using the sample application.yml file from https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry-sample-config

Does the jhipster-registry itself not read any configuration files from Git?

If I want to configure the jhipster-registry properties, should I keep overriding things on the command-line, or put a yml file somewhere? It isn't clear to me the proper way to configure it when it is a pre-built war file and has embedded bootstrap/application yml files.

Is there a way to turn on debug logging so I can see what is going on?

Answer (score 3):

This is because your JWT token isn't configured in your Git repository.
Have a look at our [sample Git repository](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry-sample-config).
The Registry will send this token to all configured applications, and thus will be able to connect to them.

Otherwise, it shows a warning as it knows this will be an issue later.

Please note that this is a difference from the "classical" Eureka and Spring Cloud Config servers, which are not secured by default.